# How to replace first parameter of most recent command?

Tags: shell, command-line

If I run a command in the terminal like this

```bsh
$ tyop --count 3 --exact haveibeenpwned
```

and the command returns with an error code, for example

`command not found: tyop`,

how can I rerun the last command keeping the command line arguments `--count 3 --exact haveibeenpwned` with another command name (for example `typo` instead of `tyop`)?

```bsh
$ typo --count 3 --exact haveibeenpwned
```

I'm looking for a shortcut, or a shell function, like `!!` or `!^`, if possible.

Comment: All BASH commands will get stored in your history. You can retrieve them with CTRL+R followed by a few consecutive characters - such as `ibeen` to present the command for possible modification, followed by enter to actually run it. You can retrieve commands from weeks ago, if you set your history file big enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
typo !*
```

From [`man bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html):

```
Word Designators
   Word designators are used to select desired words from the event.  A :
   separates the event specification from the word designator.  It may be
   omitted if the word designator begins with a ^, $, *, -, or %.  Words
   are numbered from the beginning of the line, with the first word being
   denoted by 0 (zero).  Words are inserted into the current line
   separated by single spaces.

   *      All of the words but the zeroth.  This is a synonym for `1-$'.
          It is not an error to use * if there is just one word in the
          event; the empty string is returned in that case.
```

Answer (score 9):

As well as obvious things like pressing up-arrow and manually editing the input line, [GNU Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) (as used by `bash` and several other programs) has some useful history editing features built in.  `!*` as mentioned in other answers is one of them.

Another is a string substitution feature using `^`.  From `man bash`:

> `^string1^string2^`
>
> Quick substitution.  Repeat the previous command, replacing string1 with
> string2.  Equivalent to `!!:s^string1^string2^` (see Modifiers below).

Using this, your command could be fixed by typing `^tyop^typo^` and hitting enter.

There's a lot more than can be done with bash's history.  Run `man bash` and search for `HISTORY EXPANSION` and read that section and all the sub-sections (`Event Designators`, `Word Designators`, and `Modifiers`).

BTW, it's also worthwhile reading the section headed `READLINE`, or at least skimming it to get an overview of what it's capable of.  Full documentation on readline can be found at https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html and https://tiswww.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html

Comment: For this simple of a tyop, I'd be hard pressed to decide if I was to edit and fix with this method, or grab the args with `!*`

Comment: Yeah, they both have their uses.  This quick substitution also works on arguments - it's a shortcut for a simple use of the `s//` substitution modifier - it changes the first match (e.g. run `echo foo` and then type `^foo^bar` and enter), while !* adds all of the previous command's args to the new command.

Answer (score -2):

the `!$` variable stores the last argument of the previous command.

example:

```bsh
touch hello
cat !$ #equivalent to "cat hello"
```

`!*` and `$_` store all of the arguments.

Similar question with more detail and alternative commands [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371294/how-can-i-recall-the-argument-of-the-previous-bash-command/3371299)

Comment: I am aware of that limitation, I provided a link with more useful information but I'll summarize it in the answer, thanks